# Oracle Invalid state of running

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I get the following error: Oracle Invalid state of running

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_TIME_INTERVAL

BEGIN

IF to_char(SYSTIMESTAMP,'HH:MI.AM')BETWEEN '09:10.AM' AND '04:10.PM'THEN
  dbms_output.put_line ('Time is withing range');

ELSE 

   dbms_output.put_line ('Time is out of range');

END IF;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `AS` or `IS` before the `BEGIN` to fix the syntax error.

A bigger problem is that comparing times won't work the way you're doing it. Nothing is between `'09:10.AM'` and `'04:10.PM'` because `9` comes before `4`. The AM/PM is doing you no good at the end of the string where the comparison won't see it unless all previous characters match one of the endpoints.

You should use a 24-hour format like `'HH24MI'`